# Proving $f(\mathbb{N}^*)\cap\mathbb{N}=\{1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the application $$f:\mathbb{N}^{*}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

$$n\rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$How can I prove that $f(\mathbb{N}^*)\cap\mathbb{N}=\{1\}$?

Comment: I have an idea but I don't think it's a good kick start
I tried to prove firstly that $f(\mathbb{N}^*)\cap\mathbb{N} \subset \{1\}$
and then playing with $x \in$

Comment: it's totally different there are trying to prove that the sum is never integer but read the question here

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;r\in\Bbb N\;$ be such that $\;2^r\le n!<2^{r+1}\;$ . We have

$$1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1n=\frac{ n!+\frac{n!}2+\ldots+\frac{n!}{n!}}{n!}$$

Now, $\;2^r\;$ divides the denominator *and* all the summands in the numerator above **except** one, namely $\;\frac{n!}2\;$ , and from here that the expression cannot be an integer number...